# How to make an entire <div> selectable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I've seen a couple posts about making an entire div clickable, but I'm looking to make it selectable.

What I have is a php while loop that displays a table based on user entries into a mySQL database. That code looks like this:

```php
  <div class='tracksub'>
    <div class='headname'><div class='headtext'>Name</div></div>
    <div class='headtype'><div class='headtext'>Type</div></div>
    <div class='headbrand'><div class='headtext'>Brand</div></div>
    <div class='headedp'><div class='headtext'>EDP</div></div>
    <div class='headdiameter'><div class='headtext'>Diameter</div></div>
    <div class='headflutes'><div class='headtext'>Flutes</div></div>
    <!-- <div class='headaddremove'><div class='headtext'>Add/Remove Tool</div></div> -->
</div>";

    $i = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulttable)){
        if($i%2 == 0){

            echo "<div class='even' id='" . $row['pKey'] . "'>";
            echo "<div class='name'><div class='tracktext'><a class='tracklink'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='type'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['type'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='brand'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['brand'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='edp'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['part_number'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='diameter'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['cutting_diam'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='flutes'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['flutes'] . "</div></div>";
            //echo "<div class='addremove'><form id='addremove' method='POST' action=''><button type='submit' class='addbtn' name='add" . $row['pKey'] . "'>Add</button><button type='submit' class='removebtn' name='remove" . $row['pKey'] . "'>Remove</button></form></div>";
            echo "</div>"; 

        } else {
            echo "<div class='odd'>";
            echo "<div class='name'><div class='tracktext'><a href='" . $row['image'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</a></div></div>";
            echo "<div class='type'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['type'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='brand'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['brand'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='edp'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['part_number'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='diameter'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['cutting_diam'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='flutes'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['flutes'] . "</div></div>";
            //echo "<div class='addremove'><form id='addremove' method='POST' action=''><button type='submit' class='addbtn' name='add" . $row['pKey'] . "'>Add</button><button type='submit' class='removebtn' name='remove" . $row['pKey'] . "'>Remove</button></form></div>";
            echo "</div>";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['add' . $row['pKey'] .''])){
            $add = $row['pKey'];
            $sql = "UPDATE `cutting tools` SET `qty` = `qty` + 1 WHERE `pKey` = '$add'";
            $conn->query($sql);
        }
        if(isset($_POST['remove' . $row['pKey'] .''])){
            $remove = $row['pKey'];
            $sql = "UPDATE `cutting tools` SET `qty` = `qty` - 1 WHERE `pKey` = '$remove'";
            $conn->query($sql);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</div>";
```

The divs I would like to make selectable are class="even" and class="odd" (each of these are the same, each row has an alternating background color). When A user selects this *entire row*, I would like to display certain data from the mySQL table not shown in the table where entries are selected. The layout looks something like this:

```html
<div class="rightbox">
     <div class="tbdrawer">
     </div>
     <div class="bininfo">
     <div>
     <div class="toolimg">
          <img src="" /> <!--src comes from selected mySQL row -->
     </div>
     <div class="toolinfoextra">
          <!-- a couple rows of additional info go here -->
     </div>
</div>
```

I have a few ideas about how to go about this, but for the most part I'm stumped.

1. put the class="odd" and class="even" content inside a submit button and remove all formatting - essentially making the button invisible. This way I can track which button is pressed and show the rest of the data by doing this:

```php
if(isset($_POST['. $row['pKey'] .'])){ //where the buttons name is the primary key
   $imglink = $row['image'];
   $length = $row['length'];
}
```

And so on with each piece of data I want to display. then in each div I can echo $length and so on making the specific data displayable.

2. My other idea was to use Javascript to make each selectable but I haven't had much luck with this method. As you can see, the class="even" for the div I want to be selectable has an ID equal to the primary key of that mySQL row. The idea here was so that I could do the following:

```js
"<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#" . $row['pKey'] . "" ).focus(function() {"
    $imglink = $row['image'];
"});
</script>"
```

And then essentially do the same as the PHP method where each div is echoing the variable which is only filled when the row is selected.

Where am I going wrong here? Any pointers or better ways to go about this?

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery so there's no need to generate multiple `<script>` tags. Instead, just generate one script tag that sets up the click handlers for all the `<div>` tags. Ideally it would do this `onready`. Also, why are you using the `focus` event when you want `click`?

Comment: @kmoser Not very experienced with using JS and JQuery so this was what I put together digging around a bit before I got stuck, so that's why focus and not click is used..

Comment: Could you explain the nuance between clickable and selectable? You can easily make a row clickable by putting a jquery event listener on a class. Also, could you explain where `lightbox` is located; is it just one time, or is it a part of every row?

Comment: The structure of the code is wrong. You shouldn't put the `if(isset($_POST)` lines inside your `while` loop. You should put it at the top of codes as function and make it queryable via POST request / jQuery AJAX requests.

Comment: @raptor I disagree - The table generates buttons for each individual entry in the mySQL table, putting this data inside the while loop checks each button for that specific row so I know which was pressed because the primary key for that row serves as the buttons ID. This is irrelevant though, both buttons are moving outside the table so those lines of code are being deleted anyways.

Comment: A `POST` variable shouldn't make it down to the view; look up "PRG pattern".  I understand your point, but there are other ways to do it that don't cause a back button trap.  I have a further question before I continue my answer-- where is the extra information displayed?  In the same `<div>` or in a dedicated area?  You did have a div named lightbox.  If you could show an html template for that idea it would be helpful. (sorry my first sentence sounds a bit abrupt, it's a work in progress)

Comment: @AlexPinson you can still reference specific entry using a separate function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong way to do it - You should do something like that:

```
<ul>
  <?php
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulttable)){
      echo<<<END

        <a class="table-link" id="$i" href="#">
END;
        if(i%2==0){
          echo "<li class='odd'>";
        } else {
          echo "<li class='even'>";
        }
        echo <<< END
            ...
            (here all div's)
            ...
          </li>
        </a>
        <div id="modal-$i" class="rightbox">
          <div class="tbdrawer">
          </div>
          <div class="bininfo">
            <div>
              <div class="toolimg">
                <img src="" /> <!--src comes from selected mySQL row -->
              </div>
              <div class="toolinfoextra">
                <!-- a couple rows of additional info go here -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

END;
      i++;
    }
  ?>
</ul>
```

css:

```
a.table-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.8; // for e.g.
}

a.table-link:clicked {
  background-color: blue;
}

.rightbox {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

And js:

```
for(el in document.getElementsByClassName('table-link')) {
  el.onclick = () => {
    document.getElementById('modal-$i')[0].classes.add('show')

    return false  // for cancel redirecting of href
  }
}
```

That should work for you better. You need to add somewhere button, that will have event `onclick` which would remove class `show` from your modal.

Answer (score 1):

**Separate your logic from the presentation:**

Putting your script into this standard format will prevent many heartaches and *help* prevent writing spaghetti code

```
<?php
// all processing of user input, database access, and business logic happens here

// initialize database connection here, proper connection left to reader 
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

// This is an example of PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern.  This eliminates resubmissions and back button traps
// this section roughly corresponds to the controller in MVC
if(isset($_POST['add')){
    $sql = "UPDATE `cutting tools` SET `qty` = `qty` + 1 WHERE `pKey` = ?";
    $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $pdo->execute ($_POST['id']);
    header('Location: /';
    die;
}

if(isset($_POST['remove')){
    $sql = "UPDATE `cutting tools` SET `qty` = `qty` - 1 WHERE `pKey` = ?";
    $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $pdo->execute ($_POST['id']);
    header('Location: /';
    die;
}                              

// code to get $resultTable...

// all done with logic, now show view, using php only as necessary for looping and filling in data
?>
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!— snip —>

<!— BTW, it’s OK to use tables for tabular data!  Really! —>
<div class='tracksub'>
  <div class='headname'>
    <div class='headtext'>Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class='headtype'>
    <div class='headtext'>Type</div>
  </div>
  <div class='headbrand'>
    <div class='headtext'>Brand</div>
  </div>
  <div class='headedp'><div class='headtext'>EDP</div></div>
  <div class='headdiameter'>
    <div class='headtext'>Diameter</div>
  </div>
  <div class='headflutes'>
    <div class='headtext'>Flutes</div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class='headaddremove'><div class='headtext'>Add/Remove Tool</div></div> -->
</div>

<?php $evenOdd = 'even'; ?>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulttable)):?>
  <div 
    class="<?= $evenOdd == 'even' ? 'odd' : 'even' ?>" 
    data-id="<?=$row['pKey']?>" 
    >
    <div class="name">
      <div class="tracktext"><a class="tracklink"><?=$row['name']?></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="type">
      <div class="tracktext"><?=$row['type']?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="brand">
      <div class="tracktext"><?=$row['brand']?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="edp">
      <div class='tracktext'><?=$row['part_number']?></div>
    </div>
    <div class='diameter'>
      <div class='tracktext'><?=$row['cutting_diam']?></div>
    </div>
    <div class='flutes'>
      <div class='tracktext'><?=$row['flutes']?></div>
    </div>
    <div class='addremove'>
      <form id='addremove' method='POST' action=''>

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['pKey']?>" >
        <button type='submit' class='addbtn' name='add'>Add</button><button type='submit' class='removebtn' name='remove'>Remove</button>
      </form>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Add Javascript (JQuery)**

Now that the presentation is separated from the PHP logic, it's much easier to work with the HTML/JavaScript scripting.  You don't have to mess with going in and out of quotes, single quotes vs double quotes, miles of code in between what you're doing.

Add Jquery:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     ...
```

There are at least two ways to approach this:

1. Use ajax
2. Show and hide data from the while loop

This example will use the second approach, and assume you want to use the container,

```
<div class="rightbox">
    <div class="tbdrawer">
    </div>
    <div class="bininfo">
    <div>
    <div class="toolimg">
      <img src="" /> <!--src comes from selected mySQL row -->
    </div>
    <div class="toolinfoextra">
      <!-- a couple rows of additional info go here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Add a class (`tableRow`) to your even/odd divs to be used as a hook:

```
  <div 
    class="table-row <?= $evenOdd == 'even' ? 'odd' : 'even' ?>" 
    data-id="<?=$row['pKey']?>" 
    >
```

I previously put in attribute data-id in hopes of using ajax, but for now, just add a data-image-src for the image:

```
  <div 
    class="table-row <?= $evenOdd == 'even' ? 'odd' : 'even' ?>" 
    data-id="<?=$row['pKey']?>"
    data-image-src="<?=$row['image']?>" 
    >
```

Now at the bottom of the page, add an event listener

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.table-row').on('click', function() {
      console.log( $(this).data('image');
    });
  }
</script>
```

You should see the image url in the browser console when you click on a row.

To be continued...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a solution that does what I need without using JavaScript at all - all PHP, HTML, and CSS.

Like I mentioned in the question, I decided to play with putting the row inside an "invisible" submit button. This worked better than I thought and looks like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulttable)){
                                    if($i%2 == 0){

                                        echo "<div class='even'><form method='POST'><button class='rowbtn' name='row" . $row['pKey'] . "'>";
                                        echo "<div class='name'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['name'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='type'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['type'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='brand'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['brand'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='edp'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['part_number'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='diameter'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['cutting_diam'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='flutes'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['flutes'] . "</div></div>";
                                        //echo "<div class='addremove'><form id='addremove' method='POST' action=''><button type='submit' class='addbtn' name='add" . $row['pKey'] . "'>Add</button><button type='submit' class='removebtn' name='remove" . $row['pKey'] . "'>Remove</button></form></div>";
                                        echo "</button></form></div>"; 

                                    } else {
                                        echo "<div class='odd'>";
                                        echo "<div class='name'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['name'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='type'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['type'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='brand'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['brand'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='edp'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['part_number'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='diameter'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['cutting_diam'] . "</div></div>";
                                        echo "<div class='flutes'><div class='tracktext'>" . $row['flutes'] . "</div></div>";
                                        //echo "<div class='addremove'><form id='addremove' method='POST' action=''><button type='submit' class='addbtn' name='add" . $row['pKey'] . "'>Add</button><button type='submit' class='removebtn' name='remove" . $row['pKey'] . "'>Remove</button></form></div>";
                                        echo "</div>";
                                    }

                                    if(isset($_POST['add' . $row['pKey'] .''])){
                                        $add = $row['pKey'];
                                        $sql = "UPDATE `cutting tools` SET `qty` = `qty` + 1 WHERE `pKey` = '$add'";
                                        $conn->query($sql);
                                    }
                                    if(isset($_POST['remove' . $row['pKey'] .''])){
                                        $remove = $row['pKey'];
                                        $sql = "UPDATE `cutting tools` SET `qty` = `qty` - 1 WHERE `pKey` = '$remove'";
                                        $conn->query($sql);
                                    }
                                    if(isset($_POST['row' . $row['pKey'] .''])){
                                        echo $row['pKey']; //just for testing
                                        $infoname = $row['name'];
                                    }
                                    $i++;
                                }
```

Where each row has a separate button where the name of the button is row"pKey" (e.g. row43) Formatting for the button looks like this:

```
.rowbtn{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:none;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then it's as easy as setting a variable equal to whichever mySQL `$row['tableheadername']` I need to use inside of the `if(isset())` and echoing that variable in the correct div at the beginning of the page. It may not be a perfect solution for everyone, but it's working really well for what I need and doesn't require me to introduce JS into the page.

You'll also notice I only updated the `.even` rows, I just need to copy it to the odd once done playing with formatting but the two are otherwise identical.

EDIT: all of the data coming from the selected row must come *after* the mySQL table in the code. For example:

```
<div class="leftbox">
    This is the div that contains all of my filters and table, seen above
</div>
<div class="rightbox">
    <?php echo $infoname; ?>
    This div echoes info specific to the clicked table row - and CANNOT be above 
    the "leftbox" div in the code
</div>
```